# How to Provide FocusTraversalPolicy with each JPanel defined externally and added to the JFrame or JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, focus

For Quick understanding , Pls refer to the given snapshot

[image]

I've a Jdialog **SampleTestDialog** that has some components defined on it 
along with the focus traversal order defined in `setTraversalOrder()` Method. This Dialog also uses a Separate panel defined in **SeparatePanel** Class which contain some components on it and also defines the focus order for the component defined init in the method called method called `setTraversalOrder()` defined in the same class.

**Problem:**

On pressing TAB the focus traverse on all the components defined in SampleTestDialog but
it does not enters into the SeparatePanel components

I've set `this.setFocusTraversalPolicy(focusPolicy);
        this.setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);` for SeparatePanel.

Following are the SSCCE of Two Containers used.

**SampleTestDialog.java**

```
public class SampleTestDialog extends JDialog {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel jContentPane = null;
private JLabel jLabel = null;
private JLabel jLabel1 = null;
private JTextField jTextField = null;
private JTextField jTextField1 = null;
private JPanel jPanel = null;
private JButton jButton = null;
private JButton jButton1 = null;
private SeparatePanel seperatePanel = null;

private CustomTraversalPolicyHandler focusPolicy = null;


public SampleTestDialog(Frame owner) {
    super(owner);
    initialize();

    setFocusTraversalPolicy(focusPolicy);
}

private void initialize() {
    this.setSize(392, 320);
    this.setContentPane(getJContentPane());

    setFocusTraversalOrder();
}

private void setFocusTraversalOrder() {
    Vector<Component> order = new Vector<Component>();
    order.add(getJButton1());
    order.add(getJButton());
    order.add(getJTextField1());
    order.add(getJTextField());

    focusPolicy = new CustomTraversalPolicyHandler(order);
}

private JPanel getJContentPane() {
    if (jContentPane == null) {
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints31 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints31.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints31.gridwidth = 2;
        gridBagConstraints31.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBagConstraints31.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gridBagConstraints31.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 5, 10);
        gridBagConstraints31.gridy = 3;
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints21 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints21.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints21.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gridBagConstraints21.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBagConstraints21.gridwidth = 2;
        gridBagConstraints21.gridy = 2;
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints3 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints3.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gridBagConstraints3.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints3.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gridBagConstraints3.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 0, 0);
        gridBagConstraints3.gridx = 1;
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints2.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gridBagConstraints2.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints2.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gridBagConstraints2.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 0, 0);
        gridBagConstraints2.gridx = 1;
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints1.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints1.gridy = 1;
        jLabel1 = new JLabel();
        jLabel1.setText("Text 2");
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        jLabel = new JLabel();
        jLabel.setText("Text 1:");
        jContentPane = new JPanel();
        jContentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        jContentPane.add(jLabel, gridBagConstraints);
        jContentPane.add(jLabel1, gridBagConstraints1);
        jContentPane.add(getJTextField(), gridBagConstraints2);
        jContentPane.add(getJTextField1(), gridBagConstraints3);
        jContentPane.add(getJPanel(), gridBagConstraints21);
        jContentPane.add(getSeperatePanel(), gridBagConstraints31);

    }
    return jContentPane;
}

private JTextField getJTextField() {
    if (jTextField == null) {
        jTextField = new JTextField();
        jTextField.setColumns(10);
    }
    return jTextField;
}

private JTextField getJTextField1() {
    if (jTextField1 == null) {
        jTextField1 = new JTextField();
        jTextField1.setColumns(10);
    }
    return jTextField1;
}

private JPanel getJPanel() {
    if (jPanel == null) {
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints5 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints5.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints4 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints4.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints4.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        gridBagConstraints4.gridy = 0;
        jPanel = new JPanel();
        jPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        jPanel.add(getJButton(), gridBagConstraints5);
        jPanel.add(getJButton1(), gridBagConstraints4);
    }
    return jPanel;
}

public SeparatePanel getSeperatePanel() {
    if(seperatePanel == null)
    {
        seperatePanel = new SeparatePanel();
        seperatePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "SeparatePanel", TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 12), new Color(51, 51, 51)));
        seperatePanel.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
        seperatePanel.setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);
    }
    return seperatePanel;
}

private JButton getJButton() {
    if (jButton == null) {
        jButton = new JButton();
        jButton.setText("Button 1");
    }
    return jButton;
}


private JButton getJButton1() {
    if (jButton1 == null) {
        jButton1 = new JButton();
        jButton1.setText("Button 2");
    }
    return jButton1;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    SampleTestDialog dialog = new SampleTestDialog(null);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

**SeparatePannel.java**

```
public class SeparatePanel extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JLabel jLabel = null;
private JTextField nameTextField = null;
private JLabel jLabel1 = null;
private JTextField addressTextField = null;
private JLabel jLabel2 = null;
private JTextField contactTextField2 = null;
private JPanel jPanel = null;
private JButton sendButton = null;
private JButton cancleButton = null;

private CustomTraversalPolicyHandler focusPolicy = null;

public SeparatePanel() {
    super();
    initialize();

    this.setFocusTraversalPolicy(focusPolicy);
    this.setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);

}

private void initialize() {
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints11 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints11.gridx = 1;
    gridBagConstraints11.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gridBagConstraints11.gridy = 3;
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints5 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints5.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gridBagConstraints5.gridy = 2;
    gridBagConstraints5.weightx = 1.0;
    gridBagConstraints5.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridBagConstraints5.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 0, 0);
    gridBagConstraints5.weighty = 0.0;
    gridBagConstraints5.gridx = 1;
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints4 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints4.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints4.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 0, 0);
    gridBagConstraints4.gridy = 2;
    jLabel2 = new JLabel();
    jLabel2.setText("Contact #:");
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints3 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints3.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gridBagConstraints3.gridy = 1;
    gridBagConstraints3.weightx = 1.0;
    gridBagConstraints3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridBagConstraints3.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 0, 0);
    gridBagConstraints3.gridx = 1;
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints2.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gridBagConstraints2.gridy = 1;
    jLabel1 = new JLabel();
    jLabel1.setText("Address:");
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints1.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gridBagConstraints1.gridy = 0;
    gridBagConstraints1.weightx = 1.0;
    gridBagConstraints1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridBagConstraints1.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 0, 0);
    gridBagConstraints1.gridx = 1;
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
    jLabel = new JLabel();
    jLabel.setText("Name:");
    this.setSize(300, 200);
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    this.add(jLabel, gridBagConstraints);
    this.add(getNameTextField(), gridBagConstraints1);
    this.add(jLabel1, gridBagConstraints2);
    this.add(getAddressTextField(), gridBagConstraints3);
    this.add(jLabel2, gridBagConstraints4);
    this.add(getContactTextField(), gridBagConstraints5);
    this.add(getJPanel(), gridBagConstraints11);

    setFocusTraversalOrder();
}

private void setFocusTraversalOrder() {
    Vector<Component> order = new Vector<Component>();
    order.add(getCancleButton());
    order.add(getSendButton());
    order.add(getContactTextField());
    order.add(getAddressTextField());
    order.add(getNameTextField());

    focusPolicy = new CustomTraversalPolicyHandler(order);  
}

private JTextField getNameTextField() {
    if (nameTextField == null) {
        nameTextField = new JTextField();
        nameTextField.setColumns(10);
    }
    return nameTextField;
}

private JTextField getAddressTextField() {
    if (addressTextField == null) {
        addressTextField = new JTextField();
        addressTextField.setColumns(10);
    }
    return addressTextField;
}

private JTextField getContactTextField() {
    if (contactTextField2 == null) {
        contactTextField2 = new JTextField();
        contactTextField2.setColumns(10);
    }
    return contactTextField2;
}

private JPanel getJPanel() {
    if (jPanel == null) {
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints8 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints8.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints8.gridy = 0;
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints7 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints7.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints6 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints6.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints6.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        gridBagConstraints6.gridy = 0;
        jPanel = new JPanel();
        jPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        jPanel.add(getSendButton(), gridBagConstraints7);
        jPanel.add(getCancleButton(), gridBagConstraints6);
        jPanel.add(getSendButton(), gridBagConstraints8);
    }
    return jPanel;
}

private JButton getSendButton() {
    if (sendButton == null) {
        sendButton = new JButton();
        sendButton.setText("Send");
    }
    return sendButton;
}

private JButton getCancleButton() {
    if (cancleButton == null) {
        cancleButton = new JButton();
        cancleButton.setText("Cancel");
    }
    return cancleButton;
}
}
```

To accomplish Custom focus traversal, a class **CustomTraversalPolicyHandler** is used which extends **FocusTraversalPolicy**

```
public class CustomTraversalPolicyHandler extends FocusTraversalPolicy {

Vector<Component> order;

public CustomTraversalPolicyHandler(Vector<Component> order) {
    this.order = order;
}

@Override
public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot,
        Component aComponent) {

    Component nextComponent;

    int idx = (order.indexOf(aComponent) + 1) % order.size();

    nextComponent = order.get(idx);

    if (!nextComponent.isEnabled()
            || !nextComponent.isVisible() 
            || !nextComponent.getParent().isVisible()
            || !nextComponent.getParent().isEnabled()){

        nextComponent = getComponentAfter(focusCycleRoot, nextComponent);
    }
    return nextComponent;
}

@Override
public Component getComponentBefore(Container focusCycleRoot,
        Component aComponent) {

    Component previousComponent;

    int idx = order.indexOf(aComponent) - 1;
    if (idx < 0) {
        idx = order.size() - 1;
    }

    previousComponent = order.get(idx);

    if (!previousComponent.isEnabled()
            || !previousComponent.isVisible() 
            || !previousComponent.getParent().isVisible()
            || !previousComponent.getParent().isEnabled()){

        previousComponent = getComponentBefore(focusCycleRoot,
                previousComponent);
    }

    return previousComponent;
}

@Override
public Component getFirstComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {

    return order.firstElement();
}

@Override
public Component getLastComponent(Container aContainer) {
    return order.lastElement();
}

@Override
public Component getDefaultComponent(Container aContainer) {
    return order.firstElement();
}
}
```